# Sitecore ECM 2.1 - branches, sublayouts and dynamic datasources

Tags: sitecore, datasource, newsletter, sitecore-ecm, sublayout

It's my first time implementing Sitecore ECM feature. I've cut up some html templates into layouts and sublayouts, created the datasources I needed, and made a branch template with the `$name` item set to be of template "AB Testable message".

Following Frank Rooijen's blog post: http://www.newguid.net/sitecore/2013/building-custom-newsletter-templates-for-sitecores-ecm-2-x/ I've set the body field in the `$name` to go to my message root child, set all the sublayout datasources to the relevant child items of the message root.

Andit all works fine!

What I really want to know is how the sublayout's datasource paths are derived to their new location after being instantiated from the create/insert action from the ECM Speak page.

I've been using reflector to try and get some insight, but I don't think I'm looking in the right places.

Answer (score 2):

The ECM package adds a new config file at `/App_Config/Includes/Sitecore.EmailCampaign.config`. Within that file you can see some new event handlers are added, most notably:

```
<event name="item:added">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.EmailCampaign" method="OnItemAdded" />
</event>
<event name="item:copied">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.ItemEventHandler, Sitecore.EmailCampaign" method="OnMessageCopied" />
</event>
```

If you decompile `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.dll` and look at the corresponding Class and follow through the code you will see call to `MessageRelationsCorrector.CorrectItemRelations()` which handles all the work to replace the IDs of the DataSources of new created and copied messages.

Answer (score 0):

jammykam is spot on.

The one thing that I'd add though (after banging my head for a while) is that even though the processing first does a check on template descends from AB Testable Message or the other email types, the actual correction of item relations only happens if the email template is **exactly** one of the built-in templates like AB Testable Message. Don't try and have you own template that derives. Sigh.